# Why doesn't z-index allow the OK button to be clickable?

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, z-index

I have a `#popup-shadow` div that takes all the viewport, in order to make `#popup` modal, and prevent everything *out* of `#popup` to be clickable. This works.

Problem: it even makes everything *inside* `#popup` unclickable. Why?

Since `#popup` has a higher `z-index` (value 100!), why is the OK button unclickable?

```css
#popup-shadow { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 10; }
#popup { width: 400px; background-color: #eee; z-index: 100; }
#popup-buttons div { font-size: 2em; text-align: center; padding: 15px 0; }
#popup-buttons div:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<div id="popup-wrapper">
    <div id="popup-shadow"></div>    
    <div id="popup">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
        <div id="popup-buttons">
            <div onclick="alert();">OK</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: if we remove `<div id="popup-shadow"></div>`, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z-index` doesn't affect unpositioned elements. add `position :relative` e.g. to `popup`

```css
#popup-shadow { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 10; }
#popup { position:relative; width: 400px; background-color: #eee; z-index: 100; }
#popup-buttons div { font-size: 2em; text-align: center; padding: 15px 0; }
#popup-buttons div:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<div id="popup-wrapper">
    <div id="popup-shadow"></div>    
    <div id="popup">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
        <div id="popup-buttons">
            <div onclick="alert();">OK</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `position: relative;` to `#popup`

Then it will become :
`#popup { width: 400px; background-color: #eee; z-index: 100; position: relative; }`